# What are "source" and "destination" parameters in MPI_Cart_shift?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

[Here](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Cart_shift.html) it is written that the output parameters of MPI_Cart_shift are ranks of the source and destination processes. However, in [this tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/#Virtual_Topologies) (code below) what is returned as the source process is later used in MPI_Isend to send messages. Anyone can clear it up - what actually "source" and "destination" mean?

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 16
#define UP    0
#define DOWN  1
#define LEFT  2
#define RIGHT 3

int main(argc,argv)
int argc;
char *argv[];  {
int numtasks, rank, source, dest, outbuf, i, tag=1, 
   inbuf[4]={MPI_PROC_NULL,MPI_PROC_NULL,MPI_PROC_NULL,MPI_PROC_NULL,}, 
   nbrs[4], dims[2]={4,4}, 
   periods[2]={0,0}, reorder=0, coords[2];

MPI_Request reqs[8];
MPI_Status stats[8];
MPI_Comm cartcomm;

MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);

if (numtasks == SIZE) {
  MPI_Cart_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 2, dims, periods, reorder, &cartcomm);
  MPI_Comm_rank(cartcomm, &rank);
  MPI_Cart_coords(cartcomm, rank, 2, coords);
  MPI_Cart_shift(cartcomm, 0, 1, &nbrs[UP], &nbrs[DOWN]);
  MPI_Cart_shift(cartcomm, 1, 1, &nbrs[LEFT], &nbrs[RIGHT]);

  printf("rank= %d coords= %d %d  neighbors(u,d,l,r)= %d %d %d %d\n",
         rank,coords[0],coords[1],nbrs[UP],nbrs[DOWN],nbrs[LEFT],
         nbrs[RIGHT]);

  outbuf = rank;

  for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
     dest = nbrs[i];
     source = nbrs[i];
     MPI_Isend(&outbuf, 1, MPI_INT, dest, tag, 
               MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[i]);
     MPI_Irecv(&inbuf[i], 1, MPI_INT, source, tag, 
               MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[i+4]);
     }

  MPI_Waitall(8, reqs, stats);

  printf("rank= %d                  inbuf(u,d,l,r)= %d %d %d %d\n",
         rank,inbuf[UP],inbuf[DOWN],inbuf[LEFT],inbuf[RIGHT]);  }
else
  printf("Must specify %d processors. Terminating.\n",SIZE);

MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[MPI_Cart_shift](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Cart_shift.html): Returns the shifted source and destination ranks, given a shift direction and amount

```
int MPI_Cart_shift(MPI_Comm comm, int direction, int displ, int *source, int *dest)
```

What you hand in to the function is `comm`, `direction` and `displ`. Where `direction` specifies the dimension in which the displacement is taken. The `displ`acement is the distance.

#### Example

Imagine a 2D cart topology like this (names are not ranks but process-names, only for explanation):

```
A1  A2  A3  A4  A5
B1  B2  B3  B4  B5
C1  C2  C3  C4  C5
D1  D2  D3  D4  D5
E1  E2  E3  E4  E5
```

As you might already have understood you are writing [SPMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPMD)-Code in MPI, therefore we can now pick, w.l.o.g., one process to show what is happening. Let's pick `C3`

The general idea of  `MPI_Cart_shift` is that we get the rank of a specified process in our topology.

First, we have to decide in which direction we want to go, let's pick `0`, which is the column dimension.
Then we have to specify a distance to the other process, let's say this is `2`.

So the call would be like:

```
MPI_Cart_shift(cartcomm, 0, 2, &source, &dest);
```

Now, the ranks which are placed into the `source` and `dest` variables are those respectively of the processes `A3` and `E3`.

#### How to interpret the results

I (`C3`) want to send data to the process in the same column with a distance of 2. So this is the `dest` rank.

If you do the same from the viewpoint of `A3`: process `A3` gets as its `dest` field the rank of `C3`.

And this is what `source` says: what is the rank of the process which is sending me those data if it calls the same `MPI_Cart_shift`.

If there is no process at the specified place the variable contains `MPI_PROC_NULL`.
So the results of the call at each process would look like this (with source|dest for each process, using `-` for `MPI_PROC_NULL`):

```
MPI_Cart_shift(cartcomm, 0, 2, &source, &dest);

 A1      A2      A3      A4      A5
-|C1    -|C2    -|C3    -|C4    -|C5

 B1      B2      B3      B4      B5
-|D1    -|D2    -|D3    -|D4    -|D5

 C1      C2      C3      C4      C5
A1|E1   A2|E2   A3|E3   A4|E4   A5|E5

 D1      D2      D3      D4      D5
B1|-    B2|-    B3|-    B4|-    B5|-

 E1      E2      E3      E4      E5
C1|-    C2|-    C3|-    C4|-    C5|-
```

#### Additional bit of information

If you create the cart with any dimension set `periods = 1` then there is a virtual edge between the first and the last node of the cart. In this example, `periods[0] = 1` would make a connection between `A1` and `E1`, between `A2` and `E2`, and so on. If you then call the `MPI_Cart_shift`, the counting has to be wrapped around the corners so your output would be:

```
 A1      A2      A3      A4      A5
D1|C1   D2|C2   D3|C3   D4|C4   D5|C5

 B1      B2      B3      B4      B5
E1|D1   E2|D2   E3|D3   E4|D4   E5|D5

 C1      C2      C3      C4      C5
A1|E1   A2|E2   A3|E3   A4|E4   A5|E5

 D1      D2      D3      D4      D5
B1|A1   B2|A2   B3|A3   B4|A4   B5|A5

 E1      E2      E3      E4      E5
C1|B1   C2|B2   C3|B3   C4|B4   C5|B5
```

Comment: Great answer, but shouldn't making periods[0]=1 make a connection between A1 and E1, A2 and E2, A3 and E3, A4 and E4 ?

Comment: Based on my previous usage of dimension 0 you are correct -> edited to periods[1]

Comment: @Henkersmann I agree with the previous comment: should not you change in your text "connection between `A1` and `A5`" to "`A1` and `E1`"? Because setting `periods[1]=1` corresponds to horizontal shifts and the table gives `source`|`dest` vertical pairs.

Answer (score 6):

`MPI_Cart_shift` is a convenience function. It's primary usage is for data shifts, i.e. operations in which each rank sends data in a certain direction (i.e. to `destination`) and receives data from the opposite direction (i.e. from `source`) (forward operation). When `source` is used as destination and `destination` as source, data flows in the opposite direction (backward operation). An example of such operation is the [halo swapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17591795/1374437) and it usually requires two shifts along each dimension - one forward and one backward.

`MPI_Cart_shift` is a convenience function since its action is equivalent to the following set of MPI calls:

```c
// 1. Determine the rank of the current process
int rank;
MPI_Comm_rank(cartcomm, &rank);

// 2. Transform the rank into topology coordinates
int coords[ndims];
MPI_Cart_coords(cartcomm, rank, ndims, coords);

// 3. Save the current coordinate along the given direction
int saved_coord = coords[direction];

// 4. Compute the "+"-shifted position and convert to rank
coords[direction] = saved_coord + displ;
// Adjust for periodic boundary if necessary
if (periods[direction])
   coords[direction] %= dims[direction];

// 5. Convert to rank
MPI_Cart_rank(cartcomm, coords, &destination);

// 6. Compute the "-"-shifted position and convert to rank
coords[direction] = saved_coord - displ;
// Adjust for periodic boundary
if (periods[direction])
   coords[direction] %= dims[direction];

// 7. Convert to rank
MPI_Cart_rank(cartcomm, coords, &source);
```

One could also compute the rank<->coordinate transforms using arithmetic without calls to `MPI_Cart_rank` or `MPI_Cart_coords` but it would be very inflexible as the formulas change when the dimensionality of the topology changes.

Something very important. The ranks as computed by `MPI_Cart_shift` (or by the equivalent code above) are related to the `cartcomm` communicator. Those match the ranks in the original communicator (the one used in `MPI_Cart_create`) only if `reorder = 0`. When reordering is allowed, the ranks could differ and therefore one should not use those ranks within the context of the original communicator. The following code of yours is valid but strongly dependent on the fact that `reorder = 0` in the call to `MPI_Cart_create`:

```c
dest = nbrs[i];
source = nbrs[i];
MPI_Isend(&outbuf, 1, MPI_INT, dest, tag, 
          MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[i]);
MPI_Irecv(&inbuf[i], 1, MPI_INT, source, tag, 
          MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[i+4]);
```

Here `nbrs` are computed within `cartcomm` and then used within `MPI_COMM_WORLD`. The correct code should use `cartcomm` in both communication calls:

```c
MPI_Isend(&outbuf, 1, MPI_INT, dest, tag, 
          cartcomm, &reqs[i]);
MPI_Irecv(&inbuf[i], 1, MPI_INT, source, tag, 
          cartcomm, &reqs[i+4]);
```

Some algorithms require that data travels the other way round, i.e. forward and backward are swapped. For such algorithms the displacement `displ` specified could be negative. In general, a call to `MPI_Cart_shift` with negative displacement is equivalent to a call with positive displacement but `source` and `destination` swapped.